# Xcode shortcut to move implementation method into header file

Tags: xcode, refactoring, shortcut

Does anyone know if there is a shortcut way in xcode to highlight a method within the .m file and automatically copy it to the .h file (thereby making it public)?

Currently having to copy each method is quite a chore.  Looked online but couldn't find anything so thought I would check here.

Comment: would be an excellent suggestion for XCode improvements! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't have this shortcut built in—in general a lot of the fancier refactoring features other IDEs provides Xcode lacks. If you have issues I highly, highly recommend [filing a Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) (and then publishing it on [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/) for others to dupe).

For the time being, though, [JetBrains' AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) provides this functionality along with a few other refactoring tricks.